# C# JSON de/serialize as Interface or string

Tags: c#

Using Newtonsoft.Json and given the "Greeting" class below, I'm trying to allow "Message" to be de/serialized as it does now and as a string.

```
public class Greeting
{
    public IHello Message { get; set; }
}

public interface IHello
{
    string Phrase { get; set; }
}

public class Hello1 : IHello
{
    public string Phrase { get; set; }
}

var greeting = new Greeting
{
    Message = new Hello1
    {
        Phrase = "Yo!"
    }
};

var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greeting);
```

Current output: `{"Message":{"Phrase":"Yo!"}}`
but I also want to be able to output `{"Message":"Yo!"}`

I did consider using a Generic

```
public class Greeting<T>
{
    public T Message { get; set; }
}
```

But I didn't want the user to have to know about setting

```
var greeting = new Greeting<string> { Message = "" };
```

or

```
var greeting = new Greeting<Hello1> { Message = new Hello1 { Phrase = "Yo!" }};
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired json de/serialization in another way perhaps? Or maybe I use the implementation above but hide that away somehow?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Most JSON serializer support some sort of "custom converters"... Unfortunately this question is missing information on what type of serializer you are using as well as what would cause serialization/deserialization pick "string" vs. "not a string" route. Consider to [edit] the question with this details.

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [`CustomConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). Here I've created a custom converter which can be used with `Hello1`, which simply omits some data. If you instead use the class `Hello2`, everything is included.

```
public class Hello1Converter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Hello1);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = value as IHello;
        writer.WriteValue(obj.Phrase);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var greeting = new Greeting
        {
            Message = new Hello1
            {
                Phrase = "Yo!"
            }
        };

        var greeting2 = new Greeting
        {
            Message = new Hello2
            {
                Phrase = "Yo!"
            }
        };

        var jsonText1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greeting, Formatting.Indented, new Hello1Converter());
        var jsonText2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greeting2, Formatting.Indented, new Hello1Converter());
    }
```

jsonText1:

```
{
  "Message": "Yo!"
}
```

jsonText2:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "Phrase": "Yo!"
  }
}
```

Please note that this only handles the serialization. For dezerialization you need to implement `ReadJson` as well.

And your classes:

```
public class Greeting
{
    public IHello Message { get; set; }
}

public interface IHello
{
    string Phrase { get; set; }
}

public class Hello1 : IHello
{
    public string Phrase { get; set; }
}

public class Hello2 : IHello
{
    public string Phrase { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can modify The Greeting class like this:

```
public interface IMessaging : IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable<String?>, IConvertible, IEquatable<String?>, IHello
{
}
public class Greeting
{
    public Greeting SetMessage<T>(T message) where T: IMessaging
    {
        Message = message;
        return this;
    }
    
    public object Message { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can use it either

```
var greeting = new Greeting().SetMessage("Yo");
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greeting);
```

that result `{"Message":"Yo"}`

or this way:

```
var greeting = new Greeting().SetMessage(new Hello1 { Phrase = "Yo!" });
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greeting);
```

that results `{"Message":{"Phrase":"Yo!"}}`
or you can add any interfaces you want to Greeting Class